# Store polygon type of data on the `SQLite` database

Tags: javascript, typescript, sqlite, ionic3, cordova-plugins

Can you tell me how can I store polygon type of data on the `SQLite` database?

`Note:` I'm using this [Cordova plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage).

```
polygon: Point[];

interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Recent versions of sqlite have an optional extension module for working with polygons: https://www.sqlite.org/geopoly.html

Comment: Or if you just want to store data and not do advanced queries based on the polygons, since you're using JavaScript it should be trivial to store them as json strings in a TEXT column. You can even do some manipulation and queries of that using another optional sqlite extension: https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html

Comment: I'm using this plugin. Hope I cannot use that no? @Shawn https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage

Comment: Not a clue about that.

Comment: Hope I can maintain a new table name as `Polygon` and put 3 columns there like `x` , `y` and `Id` or parent table. Hope I can do that way no? Your thoughts, please? @Shawn

Comment: That's a good approach too. You just need a way to determine the order of the vertexes in a given polygon.

Comment: True. I'll maintain the `rowid` for that. Thanks. @Shawn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Shawn pointed out, SQLite has recently implemented its own GeoPoly type - https://www.sqlite.org/geopoly.html

But the "correct" way to do this is probably using one of the various GIS standards.
Both [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) and [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) can be used to store a polygon easily in a `text` field. Or if for whatever reason you want binary, there's WKB which you can then store in a `blob` field (see the WKT link).

There are numerous tools in various languages which allow you to easily convert and handle these data types.

Note: storing as GeoPoly in SQLite will get you basic spatial capabilities. The other two won't. But if you do want spatial capabilities, but may want to consider [spatialite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/) instead.

Comment: The problem here is where I'm using this Cordova plugin. Any clue about how can I achieve that? https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage

Comment: @Sampath - the api you're using to access the database shouldn't matter because as far as it's concerned if you're using GeoJSON/WKT/WKB you're just storing another Text or Blob thing. If I'm reading that link correctly, it's using SQLite 3.22. GeoPoly is > 3.25 so you're unlikely to get that.

Comment: That's the thing what I need to know about the plugin. I'll ask this version upgrade from plugin owner. Thanks a lot for the info.